# cloning an object with entity framework 4

Tags: entity-framework

I found the following code that is supposed to clone an entity.  In my case I have a table for a person and there are multiple verticals for phone numbers, emails, etc.  When I try to clone a person entity the code appears to work fine.  However, when I try to add the object to my table I get the following error.

"The object could not be added or attached because its EntityReference has an EntityKey property value that does not match the EntityKey for this object."

I'm not quite sure what to change to make this work.

```
private static T DataContractSerialization<T>(T obj)
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcSer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            dcSer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            T newObject = (T)dcSer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            return newObject;
        }
```

Here's how I'm using the code.

```
public static void CopyData(int sourcecompanyid)
        {
            var rUtil = new CREntities();
            rUtil.Connection.Open();

            using (var r = new CREntities())
            {

                var candidates = r.Candidates.Include("Phones").Include("Emails").Where(c => c.companyId == sourcecompanyid);

                foreach (var candidate in candidates)
                {
                    ObjectParameter newcandid = new ObjectParameter("newcandid", typeof(string));

                    Candidate newcand = DataContractSerialization<Candidate>(candidate);

                    rUtil.GetNextCandId(newcandid);

                    newcand.CandID = newcandid.Value.ToString();

                    foreach (var phone in newcand.Phones)
                        phone.CandID = newcand.CandID;

                    foreach (var email in newcand.Emails)
                        email.CandID = newcand.CandID;

                    rUtil.Candidates.AddObject(newcand);
                    rUtil.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            rUtil.Connection.Close();
            rUtil.Dispose();
        }

        private static T DataContractSerialization<T>(T obj)
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcSer = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            dcSer.WriteObject(memoryStream, obj);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            T newObject = (T)dcSer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
            return newObject;
        }
```

Comment: um, why are you persisting a serialized entity? shouldn't it be the other way around? (serialize in order for transport over the wire)

Answer (score 0):

When you clone the object, the EntityKey property is probably still set. Try setting newcand.EntityKey = null directly after cloning.